# CLLocationManager does not call didEnterRegion although registers tracking for region

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I was really hesitant to post a fourth question on this subject, but triple-checked everything according to previous answers and still get bad results.

Problem: CLLocationManager does not call **didEnterRegion** in iOS6.

Setup: iOS6.

Here is the code with all the functions relevant to CLLocationManager

**myMapViewController.h**

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate,RKObjectLoaderDelegate >
{

    /* variables */

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

**myMapViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  /*  other initialization code */

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter: kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy: kCLLocationAccuracyBest];


}


- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {
  /*  other application code */

     Step* step = [_steps lastObject];    
    CLRegion *tmpReg = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:step.start_location.coordinate radius:1000 identifier: [step.start_locationLat stringValue] ];
    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:tmpReg];
    NSLog(@"Setting region with latitude %f", tmpReg.center.latitude);

}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

        NSLog(@"Monitoring region with latitude %f", region.center.latitude);
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{ 
    NSLog(@"ENTERED REGION!");
    }       
}


- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@"EXITED REGION!");

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Region monitoring failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Application runs with zero warnings and here is the log:

```
2012-12-02 19:31:41.449 myApp[5695:c07] Setting region with latitude 37.785690
2012-12-02 19:31:41.506 myApp[5695:c07] Monitoring region with latitude 37.785690
```

Comment: Your question says that `didStartMonitoringForRegion` isn't called, but the log messages say that it is called.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo, fixed.

Comment: how are you checking this?, Try the simulator, register a region then change to another simulated location and back to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you entered the region? You question doesn't actually say that you are moving your device in and out of the region you are monitoring, or simulating that movement via Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

you did not forget to put     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; ??